# VB.NET Array with multiple Variables?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

How can i do a Array with multiple Values in Vb.net ?

I have to add values to an array as like this: `MyArray.Add(Article, Pieces, Price)` and later I want to split them again like:

```
Label1.Text= MyArray.Article
Label2.Text= MyArray.Price
```

Thanks for every Answer :) !

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
    Dim myArray As New ArrayList
    myArray.AddRange("Article,Pieces,Price".Split(","c))
    Label1.Text = myArray(0) 'gives you Article
    Label2.Text = myArray(1) 'gives you Pieces
    Label2.Text = myArray(2) 'gives you Price
```

Or else you can do this using list of objects also

**Class Definition**

```
Public Class book
    Public Article As String
    Public Pieces As Int32
    Public price As Double
End Class
```

**Usage**

```
    Dim BookList As New List(Of book)
    BookList.Add(New book() With {.Article = "someArticle", .Pieces = 12, .price = 20})
    BookList.Add(New book() With {.Article = "someArticle2", .Pieces = 6, .price = 20})
    Label1.Text = BookList(0).Article 'gives you Article name in the 0th index
    Label2.Text = BookList(0).Pieces 'gives you Pieces in the 0th index
    Label2.Text = BookList(0).price  'gives you Price in the 0th index
```

Comment: Thanks :) How can i echo them with a for each loop ? When i try a simple for each loop then it echo all 2 times .. and only the first entry :o

Comment: i don't get your requirement clearly. are you using a console app?

Comment: Okey when i try to  For Each lol In myArray
            MsgBox(myArray(0) & myArray(1) & myArray(2))
        Next
Then i only get eveytime the first Array Index