# Vb.Net 2+ Strings in 1 Array Position?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

How can i add 2 and more Strings to an Array list ?

I need it for a Bill List which means i need to add Values to 1 Array Position
something like this.

```
  myarray.AddRange(Article, Price, Value)
```

and then  i need to split these again on other Point ... to get each Value to a single Variable again.

Like

```
  For each myarray in Array
  Var1 = myarray.Price
  Var2 = myarray.Value
  Next
```

Comment: Plese don't create two posts to essentially ask the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578147/vb-net-array-with-multiple-variables

Answer (score 2):

what about using a Class ?

```
Dim aBill as Bill

MyArray.Add(Bill)

 For each bill in MyArray
  Var1 = bill.Price
  Var2 = bill.Value
 Next 



  Public Class Bill        
    Property Article() As String          
    Property Price() As String
    Property Value() As String
  End Class
```

Comment: ? ... this answer isnt much helpfull ?

Comment: oh yes it is... you should use a class instead of arrays of strings , if your 3 strings is depending on each other , using position in an array is realy bad practice

Comment: then i guess iam totally confused .. can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-us/training-courses/vb-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners-8297

Answer (score 1):

> How can i add 2 and more Strings to an Array list ?

Using an *Array* of *Strings* for the item that you are adding in the *ArrayList*, with the `ArrayList.Add()` method.

An example:

```
Dim arrlist As New ArrayList
arrlist.Add({"string1", "string2", "string3"})

For Each item As String() In arrlist
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", item))
Next item
```

> and then i need to split these again on other Point ... to get each
>   Value to a single Variable again.

You could resolve both needs in several ways, in the example above you can just "cast" the items to a tuple or an Anonymous Type using **LINQ**, but a proper way would be changing the way that you are doing things then define a custom Type with two properties (`Price`, `Value`, maybe `Article`, etc) as @**Thorarins** mentioned, but as you are not friendly with that concept then to simplify things I suggest you to avoid `ArrayList`s usage for a generic `List(T)` where `T` in this case its a `KeyValuePair(Of String, String)` (you can use a tuple instead if need more than 2 strings).

An example:

```
Dim pricesList As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
pricesList.AddRange({New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("$5", "1"),
                     New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("$3", "2")})

For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In pricesList
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Price: {0}, Value {1}", item.Key, item.Value))
Next item
```

*Note that maybe you will preffer to use a proper datatype than `String` for numeric values, such as `Integer`.*

Comment: Thanks for your good Answer :) the Secound Example is right that what i want :) But how can i add now another Valuue ? ... cause it is saying to many Arguments ?